# How to call an xml file in Macro code

Tags: xml, vba

I have an essbase Macro to connect to database and i  have 3 server details in a xml file and i have to set an active flag for the same so that when it says "Y" , it has to go connect Macro with the particular server details, please let me know for any inputs

======================================================================

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()
Dim strTargetFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

 application.ScreenUpdating = False
 application.DisplayAlerts = False
 strTargetFile = "C:\Users\raji\Desktop\LoginDetails.xml"
 Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
 application.DisplayAlerts = True

 wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1")
 wb.Close False
 application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 5 
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 1 To endRow 
If Cells(r, Columns("F").Column).Value = "Y" Then 'Found

        Rows(r).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

       Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
Next r
```

From this code I am able to call the data from XML , and where the Active flag has been set to Y i was able to write the same into next sheet

Now I am trying to call the row data into EssvConnect

```
    Set myusername = Sheet2.range("B1")
    Set mypassword = Sheet2.range("C1")
    Set myServer = Sheet2.range("A1")
    Set myApp = Sheet2.range("D1")
    Set myDB = Sheet2.range("E1")

    x = EssVConnect("[Book1.xls] Sheet6", "myusername", "mypassword", "myServer", "myApp", "myDB")
     range("A1:P35").Select
     application.Run macro:="EssMenuRetrieve"
```

When I am trying to run this i am getting error "Object required", please help me out

Thanks in advance

Please use the below code and it is working fine

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    myUserName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
    myPassword = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3)
    myServer = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    myApp = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4)
    myDB = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5)




 x = EssVConnect("[Book1.xls] Sheet6", myUserName, myPassword, myServer, myApp, myDB)
            Sheets("Sheet6").Select
            range("A1:P35").Select
            application.Run macro:="EssMenuRetrieve"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you're asking for...

Comment: I have created a XML file with 3 server details .. and I have created Macro to connect to Hyperion Essbase , now I have to set a parameter in XML such as active flag so when ever the active flag show "Y"  then  macro needs to be connected to that particular server details mentioned in the XML file

Comment: Provide sample (stupid) data of XML and what have you done till now?

Comment: Try to use: `Set x = EssVConnect("[...`

Comment: I tried writing as -  Set x = EssVConnect("[Book1.xls] Sheet6", "myUserName", "myPassword", "myServer", "myApp", "myDB") and error says Object required

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Using Essbase VBA Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_client/frameset.htm?idh_using_a_hyperion_essbase_vba_function.html)

```
Sub Conn()

X=EssVConnect(Empty, "User1", "password", "Local", "Sample", "Basic")
'or
'X=EssVConnect("[SAMPVBA.XLS]", "USER1", "PASSWORD", "LOCAL", "Sample", "Basic")
End Sub
```

[Sample code](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_client/idh_sample_vbacode.html)

More you'll find here: [Essbase - library of VBA functions for use in Excel](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_client/frameset.htm?idh_essv_vbaintro.html)

Comment: I was trying the same code, but issue is for the below code X=EssVConnect(Empty, "User1", "password", "Local", "Sample", "Basic") for all the parameters like Appname , DB , Server, username and password  i have to assign variable with the data from one more sheet , i have all these details in Sheet2 ( consider ) , i am calling those values into macro by assigning variable for easch row data and call into one more sheet

Comment: When we havse server details in one sheet , and call those details into one more sheet in a macro and execute EssVconnect function, it is working with the below code

Comment: I have updated the working code in the main question itself, Thanks